# Android Studio - ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex' Duplicate entry android support v4

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, apache-httpclient-4.x

I get the error

"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/content/ContextCompatKitKat.class"

I am using apache jars for httpclient and android-support-v4.jar.

I am really new to this and am not sure why i am getting this error.

my build.gradle looks this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.petersenrr.test"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    //compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-android-4.3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
}
```

During gradle sync it is fine, just when i try to run it do i get this error.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Try to remove `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')`.  The v7 library already has the v4 library as a dependency. Also, why use JAR files at all?

Comment: And you didn't need those last 4 lines if you left the compile fileTree line uncommented

Comment: As you were answering I did remove the v4.jar and now i get this error
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/MessageConstraintException.class, I am using httpclient-4.5.2.jar, and httpclient-android-4.3.5.jar and httpcore-4.4.4.jar and the last 2 have the Message constraint in them, but i can't remove either one because i use them to import certain methods. Can i just exclude the message constraint exception on one of them?

Comment: Your apache libraries are conflicting now. I've never used those, but I'm guessing you only need the core and Android one

Comment: If you go to this site, you can see what to add to Gradle to compile your dependencies without using JAR files. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-android/4.3.5.1

Comment: Is there anyway you could give me an example of how to add to gradle to compile dependencies without a jar, just like a sample example? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll fix the problem, but go to that link and click the Gradle tab. Then copy the package name, then the same way you have the appcompat-v7 library, just make a new line like that. Starting with `compile` then the package